# Trying to build the react tutorial for reactJS

Tags: model-view-controller, reactjs

I am trying to code the reactjs tutorial in visual studio 2015 sp2 
http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html

I am just on the first step, I created the jsx file, the controller and a view file, when I run it, I just get a blank page no error, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Here is the content of the index.cshtml file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my tutorial.jsx file

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox" />
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
        Sorry I am so retarded and hard to work on that it appears impossible to get me to display. 
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Page Renders but nothing displays within the `<div>` and I am not sure why.
I had to remove the script tags for the reactjs files as the editor for this question was pitching a fit about them, they are there in my code.

What I am really looking for is how to edit jsx files in visual studio 2015 and get babel to create the js files for me. I downloaded the reactjs starter kit, but that didn't work. I finally managed to get a working environment setup by downloading all the files using npm, but I really want to be able to edit in visual studio, so I can publish the finished code to my website, which is using asp.net and targeting 4.6.1 version of the .net framework.

Comment: modified tutorial.jsx to ReactDOM.render but its still not working, wondering if I am missing a dependency or something

Comment: Would you be willing to try a react starter kit I wrote if I was sure it could work for you?

Comment: I am like mikey I will try anything lol

Answer (score 0):

did you miss your:

```
<script src="https://{cdn}/react-15.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://{cdn}/react-dom-15.0.1.js"></script>
```

i think u should add the react script

Comment: the react script is there, the editor got all wonky on me typing the question so its not included in my code for that reason, its really got me puzzled. I downloaded a github repo with it done as a webapi project and that works, but mine just will not. I have looked all over the code trying to find the difference but I just cannot find it.

Comment: just compare your code with the repo carefully, take it easy, u must have forgotten something

Comment: I think the issue is that its not exposing the component globally, found a related question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559951/running-reactjs-net-with-browserify

Comment: I still don't understand how to expose the component globally, I am sure that will be the answer on how to fix it.

Comment: Hi Thomas I think you had same problem I do, can you tell me how you fixed it. @thomasdigby still struggling with it, I have trouble following the guides